# How to Implementing MobileNetV2 into my Models?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

***I have a problem when implementing MobileNetV2, because im supeer noobs on computer vision and need to simulate with fashion-mnist datasets, lets take a look my code:***

***I've done change this code and i think im stuck on this code. Here's my MobileNetV2 code:***

```html
import torch.nn as nn

import math


def conv_bn(inp, oup, stride):
    return nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(inp, oup, 3, stride, 1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(oup),
        nn.ReLU6(inplace=True)
    )


def conv_1x1_bn(inp, oup):
    return nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(inp, oup, 1, 1, 0, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(oup),
        nn.ReLU6(inplace=True)
    )


def make_divisible(x, divisible_by=8):
    import numpy as np
    return int(np.ceil(x * 1. / divisible_by) * divisible_by)


class InvertedResidual(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inp, oup, stride, expand_ratio):
        super(InvertedResidual, self).__init__()
        self.stride = stride
        assert stride in [1, 2]

        hidden_dim = int(inp * expand_ratio)
        self.use_res_connect = self.stride == 1 and inp == oup

        if expand_ratio == 1:
            self.conv = nn.Sequential(
                # dw
                nn.Conv2d(hidden_dim, hidden_dim, 3, stride, 1, groups=hidden_dim, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_dim),
                nn.ReLU6(inplace=True),
                # pw-linear
                nn.Conv2d(hidden_dim, oup, 1, 1, 0, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(oup),
            )
        else:
            self.conv = nn.Sequential(
                # pw
                nn.Conv2d(inp, hidden_dim, 1, 1, 0, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_dim),
                nn.ReLU6(inplace=True),
                # dw
                nn.Conv2d(hidden_dim, hidden_dim, 3, stride, 1, groups=hidden_dim, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_dim),
                nn.ReLU6(inplace=True),
                # pw-linear
                nn.Conv2d(hidden_dim, oup, 1, 1, 0, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(oup),
            )

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.use_res_connect:
            return x + self.conv(x)
        else:
            return self.conv(x)


class MobileNetV2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_class=1000, input_size=224, width_mult=1.):
        super(MobileNetV2, self).__init__()
        block = InvertedResidual
        input_channel = 32
        last_channel = 1280
        interverted_residual_setting = [
            # t, c, n, s
            [1, 16, 1, 1],
            [6, 24, 2, 2],
            [6, 32, 3, 2],
            [6, 64, 4, 2],
            [6, 96, 3, 1],
            [6, 160, 3, 2],
            [6, 320, 1, 1],
        ]

        # building first layer
        assert input_size % 32 == 0
        # input_channel = make_divisible(input_channel * width_mult)  # first channel is always 32!
        self.last_channel = make_divisible(last_channel * width_mult) if width_mult > 1.0 else last_channel
        self.features = [conv_bn(3, input_channel, 2)]
        # building inverted residual blocks
        for t, c, n, s in interverted_residual_setting:
            output_channel = make_divisible(c * width_mult) if t > 1 else c
            for i in range(n):
                if i == 0:
                    self.features.append(block(input_channel, output_channel, s, expand_ratio=t))
                else:
                    self.features.append(block(input_channel, output_channel, 1, expand_ratio=t))
                input_channel = output_channel
        # building last several layers
        self.features.append(conv_1x1_bn(input_channel, self.last_channel))
        # make it nn.Sequential
        self.features = nn.Sequential(*self.features)

        # building classifier
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(self.last_channel, n_class)

        self._initialize_weights()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        x = x.mean(3).mean(2)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x

    def _initialize_weights(self):
        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                n = m.kernel_size[0] * m.kernel_size[1] * m.out_channels
                m.weight.data.normal_(0, math.sqrt(2. / n))
                if m.bias is not None:
                    m.bias.data.zero_()
            elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
                m.weight.data.fill_(1)
                m.bias.data.zero_()
            elif isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
                n = m.weight.size(1)
                m.weight.data.normal_(0, 0.01)
                m.bias.data.zero_()


def mobilenet_v2(pretrained=True):
    model = MobileNetV2(width_mult=1)

    if pretrained:
        try:
            from torch.hub import load_state_dict_from_url
        except ImportError:
            from torch.utils.model_zoo import load_url as load_state_dict_from_url
        state_dict = load_state_dict_from_url(
            'https://www.dropbox.com/s/47tyzpofuuyyv1b/mobilenetv2_1.0-f2a8633.pth.tar?dl=1', progress=True)
        model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
    return model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    net = mobilenet_v2(True)
```

```html
from torch.autograd import Variable

num_epochs = 5
count = 0
# Lists for visualization of loss and accuracy 
loss_list = []
iteration_list = []
accuracy_list = []

# Lists for knowing classwise accuracy
predictions_list = []
labels_list = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for images, labels in train_loader:
        # Transfering images and labels to GPU if available
        images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
    
        train = Variable(images.view(100, 1, 28, 28))
        labels = Variable(labels)
        
        # Forward pass 
        outputs = model(train)
        loss = error(outputs, labels)
        
        # Initializing a gradient as 0 so there is no mixing of gradient among the batches
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        #Propagating the error backward
        loss.backward()
        
        # Optimizing the parameters
        optimizer.step()
    
        count += 1
    
    # Testing the model
    
        if not (count % 50):    # It's same as "if count % 50 == 0"
            total = 0
            correct = 0
        
            for images, labels in test_loader:
                images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
                labels_list.append(labels)
            
                test = Variable(images.view(100, 1, 28, 28))
            
                outputs = model(test)
            
                predictions = torch.max(outputs, 1)[1].to(device)
                predictions_list.append(predictions)
                correct += (predictions == labels).sum()
            
                total += len(labels)
            
            accuracy = correct * 100 / total
            loss_list.append(loss.data)
            iteration_list.append(count)
            accuracy_list.append(accuracy)
        
        if not (count % 500):
            print("Iteration: {}, Loss: {}, Accuracy: {}%".format(count, loss.data, accuracy))
```

***And this is my errors***

```html
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-5ea5598f9c7c> in <module>()
     21 
     22         # Forward pass
---> 23         outputs = model(train)
     24         loss = error(outputs, labels)
     25 

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    438                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    439         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 440                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    441 
    442     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[100, 1, 28, 28] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead
```

***Thanks for your help!
I appreciate it!***

Comment: The error message provides some hints here; It’s mostly due to the tensor dimension mismatch. I would suggest debug the data’s shapes upstream to figure out the shape mismatch.

Comment: @Shao-ChuanWang yes my dataset dimension is torch.Size([100, 1, 28, 28]), could you tell me how to set dimension on my MobileNetV2 code?